Annotate emails - Images Missing when sending out email with all meta data
Want to use this feature but not able to get a hold of anyone who can help me with permissions to use this feature. And without permission I am only able to get the text meta data and images are missing when promotional email sent out.
I am working on implementing automation to send an email directly from salesforce. I have added all different meta data. But among those when email is sent out I only get the text meta data in gmail app and images are missing (Images are loading on preview tool). Need help with this issue to fix and able to see the images when email sent.
